# How to get federated user detail of WebApp in webjob on cloud

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-webjobs, webjob

We had published application on Azure with WIF implemented. We also have WebJob associated with that Web Application.

User logs in to the WebApplication, but we are not getting logged-in user details in WebJob.

WebJob is suppose to get User's Details and store in DB and Blob.

Following code in WebJob returns error -

```
    private string GetLoggedinUser()
    {
        string givenName = string.Empty;

        IClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User as IClaimsPrincipal;

        IClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = claimsPrincipal.Identity as IClaimsIdentity;

        if (claimsIdentity != null)
        {
             givenName = (from c in claimsIdentity.Claims
                                    where c.ClaimType == ClaimTypes.GivenName
                                    select c.Value).Single();


        }

        return givenName;
    }
```

Above code throws error "object not referenced" i.e. null object error in "HttpContext.Current"

Comment: You don't have access to user details in webjob because webjob runs in its own process. Is it a triggered job ?

Comment: @Thomas, It is continuous Job.

Comment: @Thomas, is there any work around to get user details in webjob?

Comment: Sorry but are you using a queue servicebus trigger ? Maybe you need to pass username to your job so that it can grab user details

Comment: @Thomas, It is a QueueTrigger.

Comment: Are you using Azure AD ?

Comment: @Thomas, Yes I am using AD

Comment: @Thomas, I can't pass userdetail in a Queue as it is getting populated by another webjob which reads from DB and writes it in a Queue. whereas user details can be available only when user logged-in in an application at runtime.

Comment: So can you pass the username or user id(objectid in Azure AD) in your queuemessage ? so that the webjob can call the azure ad to grab information about the user

Comment: Does it make sense to you ?

Comment: Hey Anil, do you need more help one your problem ?

Comment: @Thomas, I think it cannot read user details as it runs on another thread as windows server whereas user logged-in in a webapplication, both runs on different threads

Comment: Yeah but you can add the username or userid to the queue message. So in your webjob you can call the azure ad to get the user details

Comment: @Anil, What's you purpose you store your user details into your DB using webjob? I think you can store your user info directly into DB and set the user objectid as unique key.

Comment: @WillShao-MSFT, Well purpose is to know who was the logged-in user when the job ran.

Comment: @AnilPurswani,Generally speaking, we can store the logged-in user information into database directly. How do you think it?